# Why is this event being handled twice in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

For some reason the below code makes the links' click event fire twice. I'm relatively new to knockout and I think I might have done my custom binding wrong. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? (Btw, the reason I didn't post a fiddle is that I can't include the mapping plugin from github on jsfiddle.)

JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.activityContent = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
        var content = document.createElement("p");
        content.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="text: user_name, click: $parent.NavigatePage.bind($data, \'profile\', user_id)"></a>';
        element.appendChild(content);
        ko.applyBindings(bindingContext, content);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};

var activities = ko.mapping.fromJS({Activities: [{
    "user_id": "52b5042d572b94ceadf6asdf1a2a5bc",
    "user_name": "Sean Templeton"
}, {
    "user_id": "52b5042d57asfda2b94ce61a2a5bc",
    "user_name": "Sean Templeton"
}, {
    "user_id": "52b5042d572b94ce61a2a5bc",
    "user_name": "Sean Templeton"
}, {
    "user_id": "52b5042d5asdfasdf72b94ce61a2a5bc",
    "user_name": "Sean Templeton"
}, {
    "user_id": "52basdf5042d572b94ce6asdf1a2a5bc",
    "user_name": "Sean Templeton"
}], NavigatePage: function(page, userId) { console.log(this); console.log(page); console.log(userId()); }});

ko.applyBindings(activities);
```

html:

```
<Ul data-bind="foreach: Activities">
    <li data-bind="activityContent: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which version of KO are you using? Why do you put together html in your handler? Why don't you just inline or have a separate template (http://jsfiddle.net/eTXQJ/)?

Comment: Because the innerHTML is dynamic, and Knockout v3.x

Comment: Are you sure about the KO version? Because your code throws the "Message: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." error when using KO3.0 http://jsfiddle.net/hLpzB/ If I use some quite old KO version like 2.2.1 only then I can repro this double executed click behavior...

Comment: yeah, sorry, for KO.3.x you need to stopBinding on the parent for that to work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ko.applyBindings(bindingContext, content);` line in your `init`, and remember that `update` runs once on init, and then on each update.

Also, you have a larger problem.  In the fiddle given above by @nemesv, by not removing the `ko.applyBindings()` from the custom binding, the list isn't even iterated the full 5 times.

**A DIFFERENT APPROACH**

Unless you have great plans for the `activityContent` binding beyond this example, you could dispense with the custom binding and simply register a delegate event on your `<li>` element in your viewModel.  You could then use Knockout's `ko.dataFor()` to determine what's been clicked on, and then call NavigatePage().  This approach is far more performant and does not require a custom binding.

You can read about delegate events [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html).

Comment: the issue with that is we don't use jQuery where at all possible, as we are phasing it out of our application completely. In addition, this breaks our application flow as the only place html elements are located are in our templates/views.

Comment: but that is an interesting look on it, and maybe another similar approach can be found later